# output decision tree in the pipeline manner

Tags: python, pipeline, decision-tree

Hi as I am new to machine learning methods using the sklearn library, I try to incorporate the decision tree into pipeline and then make both the prediction and output of the model, but as I run the following code, I got the warning:

'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'tree_'

So I wonder if the pipeline does not support with tree output, and how am I able to fix this problem? I have also tried using the decision_tree class directly, but I got another warning that: 
setting an array element with a sequence.
I know that this appears as I have vectors with different dimension, but still no clue how to deal with the situation.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree.export import export_text
from sklearn import tree


# a function that reads the corpus, tokenizes it and returns the documents
# and their labels
def read_corpus(corpus_file, use_sentiment):
    documents = []
    labels = []
    with open(corpus_file, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            tokens = line.strip().split()

            documents.append(tokens[3:])

            if use_sentiment:
                # 2-class problem: positive vs negative
                labels.append( tokens[1] )
            else:
                # 6-class problem: books, camera, dvd, health, music, software
                labels.append( tokens[0] )

    return documents, labels

# a dummy function that just returns its input
def identity(x):
    return x

# read the data and split i into train and test
X, Y = read_corpus('/Users/dengchenglong/Downloads/trainset', use_sentiment=False)
split_point = int(0.75*len(X))
Xtrain = X[:split_point]
Ytrain = Y[:split_point]
Xtest = X[split_point:]
Ytest = Y[split_point:]

# let's use the TF-IDF vectorizer
tfidf = False

# we use a dummy function as tokenizer and preprocessor,
# since the texts are already preprocessed and tokenized.
if tfidf:
    vec = TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor = identity,
                          tokenizer = identity)
else:
    vec = CountVectorizer(preprocessor = identity,
                          tokenizer = identity)


# combine the vectorizer with a Naive Bayes classifier
classifier = Pipeline( [('vec', vec),
                        ('cls', tree.DecisionTreeClassifier())])


# train the classifier on the train dataset
decision_tree = classifier.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)


# predict the labels of the test data 
Yguess = classifier.predict(Xtest)
tree.plot_tree(classifier.fit(Xtest, Ytest)) 
# report performance of the classifier
print(accuracy_score(Ytest, Yguess))
print(classification_report(Ytest, Yguess))
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

# combine the vectorizer with a Naive Bayes classifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier = make_pipeline(vec,clf)
```

As it seems, before using pipeline you must initiate the model you are trying to apply. Let me know if this works and if not, the errors it's returning.
From: [Scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)
Example out of: [Make pipeline example with trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_feature_transformation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-feature-transformation-py)

Comment: doesn't work... the same warning holds, seems like the pipeline does not support functions in tree?

Comment: Edited answer... Check that?

Comment: In any case I believe if you follow the second link I shared, you should be able to make the trees work within your pipeline. Let me know if there's any issue with this new asnwer

Answer (score 0):

I think you could change your code here:

```
tree.plot_tree(classifier.fit(Xtest, Ytest))
```

into:

```
tree.plot_tree(decision_tree.named_steps['cls'])
```

as named_steps is an attribute of your fitted pipeline. See [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for more details.